# List files with last access date in linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'd like to clean up a server that my webmaster let turn into a mess.

I know how to list all files not accessed within the last x days using find and -atime, but what I'm looking for is to come up with a listing of the last access date for files one level down in directory `/foo`:

```
/foo/bar1.txt Dec 11, 2001
/foo/bar2.txt Nov 12, 2008
/foo/bar3.txt Jan 12, 2004
```

For folders one level down in directory `/foo`, list the date of the most recently accessed file within the directory (no limit on depth for identifying last access date)

```
/foo/bar1/ Feb 13, 2012
/foo/bar2/ Oct 11, 2008
```

Where `/foo/bar1/` has a file modified Jan 1, 1998 and Feb 13, 2012 and `/foo/bar2/` has 30 files, most recent of which was accessed Oct 11, 2008.

This question is similar to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5566310/how-to-recursively-find-and-list-the-latest-modified-files-in-a-directory-with-s but rather than the modification date, the date of interest is the last accessed date.

Comment: Was the fs mounted with the "noatime" option? If so, you're sunk.

Comment: Nay. I was able to list individual files earlier/later than x days using find & -atime.

Answer (score 2):

```
find /foo/* \( -type d ! -name . -prune \) -exec ls -lu {} \;


find /foo/* \( -type d ! -name . -prune \) | 
while read dir
do
    find $dir -type f -exec  stat -c "%X %n %x" {} \; |
          sort -rn | head -1 | awk '{print $2, $3, $4}'
done
```

Try those.

Comment: Your script fails in directories that have files with spaces in them.